# como hacer una consulta con fecha

Tags: php, mysqli, sql

nececito hacer una consulta a la **base de datos** que me traiga todo donde la **fecha** sea igual a la seleccionada , estoy usando una libreria de **boostrap** para los input de tipo fecha.

Al momento de elegir una fecha del input se ejecuta un **script js** con **ajax** envio el valor capturado del input fecha a la base de datos este es el script

```
//este funcion change.datetimepicker captura la fecha seleccionada

 $("#datetimepicker4").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {

       var f=e.date //esto devuelve un objeto con la fecha seleccionada es 

       var fecha=JSON.stringify(f) //la fecha capturada ej: 2019-02-20

          console.log(fecha) //2019-02-20
```

una vez capturada la fecha procedo con **ajax** a enviar la fecha a la base de datos ej:

```
 var url="../ajax/fecha.php";

   $.ajax({

          url:url,
          type:"post",
          data:{fecha:fecha},
          datatype:"JSON",

      }).done(function(response){

            alert(response)

          }).fail(function(response){

              console.log(response)

          }); 

        });
```

**escript php**

```
$fecha=$_POST["fecha"];//recivir fecha por post


$sql=$con->query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE fecha='$fecha'");


if($sql->num_rows > 0){

echo"Se encontraron registros"; 

}else{

    echo"No se encontraron registros"; //siempre entra aqui 
}
```

> **NOTA:** el campo de la fecha es de tipo **DATETIME** el cual guarda la fecha,
>   ,hora, minutos y segundos

Alguien me puede ayudar a ejecutar este codigo correctamente nunca me habia tocado hacer consultas con fechas y ahora pues tengo la nececidad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tendrás que asegurarte de que la columna 'fecha' en la tabla y la variable `$fecha` tienen el mismo formato.

Por tu código, parece que `$fecha` tiene formato `DATE` (`2019-02-20`) y la columna tiene formato `DATETIME` (`2019-02-20 00:00:00`).

Puedes usar la función `CAST()` de MySQL para convertir `$fecha` a formato `DATETIME`:

```
$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE fecha=CAST('$fecha' AS DATETIME)");
```

Si no te interesan las horas ni los minutos y quieres comprobar solamente el día, puedes castear los valores de la columna:

```
$sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE CAST(fecha as DATE)='$fecha'");
```

Comment: genial gracias bro funciono perfectamente lo de `cast()`